# Need advice on Tomcat6 and Oracle 11g app deployment

Tags: tomcat6

This is my very fist question in this forum; so please bear with me for any mistakes or incompleteness.

We have a Web application deployed under Tomcat 6.0.20 and Oracle 10g set up and it ran perfectly fine without issues for the last one year or so. This week we have migrated to a new server environment. The ONLY thing that changed were Tomcat 6.0.35 and Oracle 11g. I am using the same odbc14.jar for database connection pooling.

While the application seems to run fine, I am seeing JVM Full Thread dumps appearing in catalina.out about every 10 minutes or so (even when there are no apparent activities at the application side).

The application performance doesn't seem to be impacted so far but I wanted to know if I should be concerned about these thread dump messages.

Both tomcat and Oracle are running under Solaris 10 (in separate physical boxes)

Any advice will be very helpful. Let me know if a thread dump snapshot will be more helpful to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a known problem with the combination of 11g and odbc14.jar
You should be using ojdbc6.jar - that may or may not solve your problem, but it's the first thing that I'd try before looking elsewhere.

BTW, if you're upgrading tomcat, why 6.0.35 and not 7.x - 7.0.27 is out now?

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. I will certainly try with ojdbc6.jar and see if it makes a difference. BTW, I understand I might need to recompile the code-base with ojdbc6.jar - is this a correct understanding?

Comment: Sorry hit the send button too quickly.... yes Tomcat 7 was in my mind but I was somewhat nervous since I have never used it before :) and this server migration had to happen in a very short notice...Will certainly give it a try in near future.. Thanks again

Comment: more update.. i have just now installed tomcat7 with ojdbc6.jar (in a separate test server) and the problem (JVM thread dump) seems to have gone... thx so much for the suggestion